# PING URL through UDP broadcast in android?

Tags: android, url, udp, ping, broadcast

I seriously dun have much knowledge about UDP broadcast.

I looked over some examples over the internet for it, but they went way over my head.

What i need to do is create UDP broadcast connection, send and recieve packets.

Plus also ping some URL's or IP addresses.

Can anyone provide a solution?

A good example would be considered!

Comment: Ping requires the ICMP protocol not UDP.

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as a 'UDP broadcast connection'. Connections imply unicast. 2. There is no such thing as ping in UDP. 3. There is no such thing as pinging a URL. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Getting the Broadcast Address

You need to access the wifi manager to get the DHCP info and construct a broadcast address from that:

```
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow
int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
byte[] quads = new byte[4];
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
  quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
```

}

Sending and Receiving UDP Broadcast Packets

Having constructed the broadcast address, things work as normal. The following code would send the string data over broadcast and then wait for a response:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
    getBroadcastAddress(), DISCOVERY_PORT);
socket.send(packet);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/downloads/list

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example

http://sourcecodemania.com/udp-datagram-sockets-in-java/

Comment: thnx i will run n let u knw if i encounter some problem